# trying to work with shell script which is causing an error

Tags: shell, grep, cut

```
echo “enter the login of the user” 

read name

logindetails=`who|grep –w “$name” | grep “tty” `

if [ $? –ne 0 ]
then
    echo “$name has not logged in yet”
    exit
fi

loginhours=`echo “$logindetails” | cut –c 26,27`
loginminuts=`echo “$logindetails” | cut –c 29-30` 

hoursnow=`date | cut –c 12,13`
minnow=`date | cut –c 15,16` 

hour=`expr $loginhours - $hoursnow`
min=`expr $loginminuts - $minnow`

echo “ $name is working since $hour Hrs - $min Minuts”
```

A shell script that determines the period for which a specified user is working on the system.

Comment: I'm assuming I formatted that correctly. What isn't working? What is this supposed to do exactly?

Comment: 3 possible things (1 definite), 1. Add topline she-bang `#!/bin/bash`. 2. make file executable with `chmod +x myScript.sh` ; 3. If file passed thru an MSWindows machine, do `dos2unix myScript.sh`. Good luck.